# SSL Cert with exportable private key

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, private-key

I got a trial server certificate from completeSSL with the plan to use it to sign my Azure production site.  It turns out that I need a certificate with an exportable private key ... and my new trial certificate is not such.

Does anyone know which of the ssl vendors sell certificates with exportable private key?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "exportable?" As in, "legally exportable from the country," or as in, "extractable from the key store," or something else?

Comment: Hi Eric: An exportable private key cert is one that allows you to extract the private key (for say ... transferring the cert to another machine). For further info, please google "exportable private key".

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg57987.html "The concept of "unexportable" without a HSM [hardware device] is rather doubtful anyway and is
more security by obscurity: if you know how the key is stored you can extract
it anyway." -- Dr Stephen N. Henson. OpenSSL project core developer.